# I only know folio number and do not have any document regarding my share

Tags: stocks, india

My father have bought shares of a company and he does not remember anything about it.  I just got a dividend cheque from the company which consists of folio number.  How can I get information about the share and how can I get it transfer to my demat account.  I also don't know the bank which consists this share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just got a dividend cheque from the company which consists of folio number

Assuming that these are physical shares. The dividend cheque should give you the details of Share, the number of Shares held. The envelope that came with it should have details of the registry that manages the services. Write to then and explain. You may have to provide the required paperwork. They will also tell you the process to convert to electronic/demat and required paperwork to transfer to your account.

**Edit:**
As your father does not have demat, these are held as Physical Share certificates [Not with any Bank]. Write to the registrar of company saying you have lost the Originals and need to convert into electronic form and transfer to your demat account. Your Bank where you hold the Demat Account will also help you complete the processes.

Comment: I know the company name , number of shares I own but I do not know which Bank hold these shares, As my father do not have any demat account .

Comment: If I got dividend cheque does that mean shares are not in any bank?

Comment: @totoro: Getting the divided check only means you have not arranged for the divided to be deposited directly into a bank account or reinvested in additional shares.